# CSS - Style multiple ids in class

Tags: css, class, styles

I want this css code to work:

```
#inventoryGarbageSpot .id1,.id2,id3,id4{
padding:0px;
padding-top: 0px;
width:35px;}
```

If I write one id instead of multiple ids it works.

Thanks for your help,

Rotem

Answer (score 2):

If we decompose your selector, you're targeting :

- `#inventoryGarbageSpot .id1`
- `.id2`
- `id3`
- `id4`

First, there're 2 non-existent elements : `id3` and `id4`, which will stand for this kind of elements :

```
<id3></id3>
<id4></id4>
```

Secondly, you need to repeat your `#inventoryGarbageSpot` before each class.

Instead of this unefective selector, use this one :

```
#inventoryGarbageSpot .id1,
#inventoryGarbageSpot .id2,
#inventoryGarbageSpot .id3,
#inventoryGarbageSpot .id4 {
    padding:0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width:35px;
}
```

If you want to generalize your selector, you can use an attribute selector, as mentioned by Sudharsan.

Answer (score 1):

Use [attribute selector](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/css3-attribute-selectors/) like this

style be

```
  #inventoryGarbageSpot [class^="id"]{
    padding:0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width:35px;
    }
```

that should be

```
[class^="id"]{

   // here style

}
```

Comment: Can you write your code with the example of "id1,id2,id3,id4" please

Comment: I still cant understand where to put the ".id1,.id2,.id3,.id4" :(

Comment: you want static ids like id1, id2 to id4 follow zessex answer. if you want dynamic means follow my answer thanks

Comment: please put the code in your css file it will work don't worry first try